How can I place the number of an <li> in an <ol> in the center vertically?
I am working on the design, but I want the number to be aligned in the center vertically, I've been stuck on this for over an hour.



#ScoresList {
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
  list-style-position: inside;
  /*Opgezocht*/
}

#ScoresList li {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  background-color: var(--normal-background);
  text-align: left;
}

.ScoreItem {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.ScoreItem__Score {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.ScoreItem__Date {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.ScoreItem__Details {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 3;
}
<ol id="ScoresList">
  <li>
    <div class="ScoreItem">
      <p class="ScoreItem__Score">Score: <span>2500</span></p>
      <p class="ScoreItem__Date">On: <span>25/03/2024</span></p>
      <details class="ScoreItem__Details">
        <summary>More details</summary>
        <p>score</p>
        <p>tijd</p>
        <p>aantal fouten</p>
        <p>foutpercentage</p>
        <p>datum</p>
      </details>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>



I have tried a lot, even with li::marker and such but I just cannot get the number to move, only if I do text-align: center it moves it to the center horizontally, but not vertically.

Do you really need list style type position? if you remove it then they will be aligned.

Please check that your snippet demonstrates the problem, it doesn’t on Safari/IOS 16… for me.

At the very least the div is a block item and so is 100% wide. display: inline-grid; is probably a better choice rather than display: grid;

Use CSS-Counters to create the marker in a pseudo-element and then use flexbox on the li.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

#ScoresList {
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
  list-style-position: inside;
  /*Opgezocht*/
  width: 50vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
}

#ScoresList {
  counter-reset: l1;
}

#ScoresList li {
  //margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  background-color: var(--normal-background);
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  counter-increment: li;
  align-items: center;
}

#ScoresList li::before {
  content: counter(li) ":";
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.ScoreItem {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.ScoreItem__Score {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.ScoreItem__Date {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.ScoreItem__Details {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 3;
}
<ol id="ScoresList">
  <li>
    <div class="ScoreItem">
      <p class="ScoreItem__Score">Score: <span>2500</span></p>
      <p class="ScoreItem__Date">On: <span>25/03/2024</span></p>
      <details class="ScoreItem__Details">
        <summary>More details</summary>
        <p>score</p>
        <p>tijd</p>
        <p>aantal fouten</p>
        <p>foutpercentage</p>
        <p>datum</p>
      </details>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>



